# How can I deploy an OpenTelemetry Collector for Rails on same Heroku network?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I have a Rails API running on heroku and would like to instrument it. I currently have a collector configured, however I don't know how to deploy this collector without hosting it another server, which would in turn require authentication from my API. Is there a way to deploy the collector in Heroku so that it would be running in the same network as the API, hence enabling the use of localhost for the connections?

I thought that maybe I could use a Dynos for this, however Dynos are isolated from one another, so the connection wouldn't be as simple as using localhost.
I want to find a way to be able to run my collector alongisde my API so that no authentication is required and I can use localhost for the endpoints.
Thanks for the help in advance!